# Access list items by name in R using another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, pointers, subset

I am trying to access an item in a list using the name stored in another variable, however I get an error that the object does not exist.  Any solution for this?  I've spent two days now looking for one :)

Working Example:

```
# create a list
master <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
names(master) <- c("d", "a1", "b", "c")  #4123
master[["a2"]] <- 25

# set up the problem
callname <- "a2"

callname <- paste("master", callname, sep="$")

# Try to call up the value based on the name:
callvalue <- get(callname)
# This gives error: "Error in get(callname) : object 'master$a2' not found" 

# However, calling the object directly prints the value correctly:
master$a2
# [1] 25
```

In reality I have a list of 130 dataframes, belonging to ten groups (names are group01.1, group01.2, group02.1, etc).  I need to bind_rows() all of group01.X into a single dataframe, group02.X into another, and so on.  I would much prefer to do this programmaticly rather than one by one.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: INstead, it would be `callname <- "a2";get("master")[[callname]]
#[1] 25`

Comment: Thank you akrun!  I have some complications when I expand this to my real-world, but must run to catch my bus, so I'll get back to this in the morrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the  `list` object with `get` and then use `[[`

```
callname <- "a2"
get("master")[[callname]]
#[1] 25
```

---

Or if we want to use `eval`uate the whole string (not recommended)

```
callname <- paste("master", callname, sep="$")
eval(parse(text = callname))
#[1] 25
```